# Erasing a CSS attribute inherited from a CSS file using in-line CSS

Tags: css, jsp

I know that you can override a **CSS** attribute that a **jsp** page inherits from a jsp include CSS file (i.e. a global CSS file).
But what if there is an attribute within a element that is messing up a particular page and I want to not have it being used in that page only using in-line CSS? For example, right now I have this in my include CSS file:

```
#breadcrumb { width: 100%; border: 2px solid white; font-size: 9px; color: #330066; margin-top: 0; }
```

But the width: 100% is messing up the look of one of my jsp page. I want to not use width: 100% in that page for #breadcrumb through in-line CSS, so what would I have to put into this on that jsp page so it doesn't use that attribute in #breadcrumb:

```
<style> 
#breadcrumb {

}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `!important` to override the inline style.

```
<style>
#breadcrumb {
    width: auto !important; /* or whatever value you need */
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea: !important should be avoided cause it breaks cascading rules.

Comment: @Ioan: It's the only option if he wants to override the inline style with a rule in a `<style></style>` block.

Comment: @Jason You're right. I mixed up normal inline styles with !important inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

Add `style` attribute to your element - for example

```
<div style="width:20%;"></div>
```

It will override other css rules - it has highest priority